# Airpods Pro Nosie cancellation not showing up on my Macbook Pro, how to turn the noise cancellation on?

Tags: airpods

My airpods pro noise cancellation works fine with my iPhone.

And the airpods pro is also correctly connected to my MacBook pro.

However, I can't find the noise cancellation toggle and it's not working. I can still hear the noise as if I am in the "transparency mode".

This is what the official page says:https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210643

[image]

This is what I saw:

[image]

Comment: Are you running Mojave or Catalina on your MBP? [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374418/airpods-pro-on-mojave?rq=1) at AskDifferent may have some clues.

Comment: I have updated to the latest Catalina.